# GOOGLE LINE CHART ERROR: All series on a given axis must be of the same data type. EMPTY QUERY

Tags: charts, google-visualization, line

i've a problem with a line chart which displays the error "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" when a query gives null result or no rows.

If you look carefully there are 7 queries (everyone draw a line on the same chart), if any query gives back an empty result (no rows) i get the error in the topic title. When all queries are not empty, chart correctly works.

Is there a way to avoid this error ?

```
<?php
$curyear = date('Y');
 $con = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx');
?>
<html>
     <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {
var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'LaMotta'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as LaMotta, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ01' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['LaMotta']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);

var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Spadone'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Spadone, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ02' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Spadone']."],";

         }
        ?> 

       ]);

var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Ivo'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Ivo, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ11' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Ivo']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);


 var data4 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Montagliani'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Montagliani, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ12' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Montagliani']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);

  var data5 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Galtieri'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Galtieri, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ21' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Galtieri']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);


  var data6 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Giacometti'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Giacometti, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ22' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Giacometti']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);


  var data7 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Mantovani'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Mantovani, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ23' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Mantovani']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);



var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, data3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1,2], [1]);
var joinedData3 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData2, data4, 'full', [[0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3], [1]);
var joinedData4 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData3, data5, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4], [1]);
var joinedData5 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData4, data6, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4,5], [1]);
var joinedData6 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData5, data7, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1]);

// sort by start and end dates


var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
chart.draw(joinedData6, {
    height: 500,
    width: 1400,
    interpolateNulls: true,

});
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body><br /><br />  
       <div style="width:1500px;" align="center">  
                <h1 align="center" style="font-size:22px">Produzione SMARTEASY: MYENNOVA (Ultimi 10 Mesi)</h1>  
            <br />  
            <div align="center" id="piechart2" style="float:left; width: 700px; height: 390px;"></div> 
            <div align="center" id="piechart1" style="float:left; width: 700px; height: 390px;"></div>   
       </div>
    <!--Divs that will hold the charts-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a data view to draw the chart,
and only include columns from the joined data that have values.

using data table method `getColumnRange`,
we can determine if the column has data.

columns that don't have data,
`getColumnRange` will return `null` for both `min` & `max`

```
// build view columns
var viewColumns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < joinedData6.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  var range = joinedData6.getColumnRange(i);

  // determine if column has values
  if (!((range.min === null) && (range.min === null))) {
    viewColumns.push(i);
  }
}

// build data view
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData6);
view.setColumns(viewColumns);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
chart.draw(view, {  // <-- use view to draw chart
  height: 500,
  width: 1400,
  interpolateNulls: true,
});
```

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'LaMotta'],
    ['test1', 5],
    ['test1', 6],
    ['test1', 7],
  ]);

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Spadone'],
  ]);

  var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Ivo'],
    ['test3', 8],
    ['test3', 9],
    ['test3', 0],
  ]);

  var data4 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Montagliani'],
  ]);

  var data5 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Galtieri'],
    ['test5', 1],
    ['test5', 2],
    ['test5', 3],
  ]);

  var data6 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Giacometti'],
  ]);

  var data7 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Mantovani'],
    ['test7', 4],
    ['test7', 5],
    ['test7', 6],
  ]);

  var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
  var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, data3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1,2], [1]);
  var joinedData3 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData2, data4, 'full', [[0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3], [1]);
  var joinedData4 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData3, data5, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4], [1]);
  var joinedData5 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData4, data6, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4,5], [1]);
  var joinedData6 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData5, data7, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1]);

  // build view columns
  var viewColumns = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < joinedData6.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    var range = joinedData6.getColumnRange(i);

    // determine if column has values
    if ((range.min !== null) || (range.max !== null)) {
      viewColumns.push(i);
    }
  }

  // build data view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData6);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, {  // <-- use view to draw chart
    height: 500,
    width: 1400,
    interpolateNulls: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your example script on mine. But i've some difficulty cause i dont know but seems some tag is missing.
I've completely removed the final part of my script, putting your inside. But at the beginning of the page need I to remove what ? I'll add what i've done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$curyear = date('Y');
 $con = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx');
?>

    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart']
      }).then(function () {
var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'LaMotta'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as LaMotta, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ01' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['LaMotta']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);

var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Spadone'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Spadone, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ02' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Spadone']."],";

         }
        ?> 

       ]);

var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Ivo'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Ivo, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ11' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Ivo']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);


 var data4 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Montagliani'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Montagliani, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ12' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Montagliani']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);

  var data5 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Galtieri'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Galtieri, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ21' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Galtieri']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);


  var data6 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Giacometti'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Giacometti, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ22' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Giacometti']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);


  var data7 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Mantovani'],
         <?php 
            $query = "SELECT responsabile, sum(val_fattu) as Mantovani, data_dichiarato FROM dichiarati_myennova WHERE responsabile = 'ADMRZ23' and dichiarati_myennova.DATA_DICHIARATO > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 DAY) GROUP BY MONTH(data_dichiarato), responsabile ORDER BY data_dichiarato";
            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

            echo "['".date("Y/m", strtotime($row['data_dichiarato']))."',".$row['Mantovani']."],";


         }
        ?> 

       ]);



var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, data3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1,2], [1]);
var joinedData3 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData2, data4, 'full', [[0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3], [1]);
var joinedData4 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData3, data5, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4], [1]);
var joinedData5 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData4, data6, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4,5], [1]);
var joinedData6 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData5, data7, 'full', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1]);

// sort by start and end dates

    // build view columns
   var viewColumns = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < joinedData6.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
   var range = joinedData6.getColumnRange(i);

// determine if column has values
if ((range.min !== null) || (range.max !== null)) {
  viewColumns.push(i);
    }
  }

  // build data view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData6);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, {  // <-- use view to draw chart
height: 500,
width: 1400,
interpolateNulls: true,
  });
 });
```

Comment: MAYBE DID IT :) Eliminating from Database the 0 rows :)